# How to pass open weather API data to React front-end with serverless function and axios

Tags: reactjs, serverless

I'm currently attempting to call the openweather `API` in a serverless function, pass the response into a 'return' and then get the response with `Axios` and set my component state with the response.

However, every time it calls the `JSON` isn't being sent in the response. Instead, it's just the URL. The state is then updated to be the URL unsurprisingly.

When I call the `API` in `Postman`, it returns the data. So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

The serverless function is obviously wrong. But what do I need to change about my serverless function to return the data, and not just the `URL`?

Here's the function:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {

    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=${process.env.OPEN_WEATHER_API}`;

    const weatherResponse = url;

    return res.status(200).json(weatherResponse);
  };
```

And then my Axios call in my component calling the serverless function:

```
this.state = {

      weather: []

    }

  axios.get("/api/getCurrentWeather")
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      weather: response.data
    })
    console.log(this.state.weather)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your client you are calling server less function `/api/getCurrentWeather`

now in you serverless function you must call the openweather api using axios of http [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs)
and then send error or success data to your client.

```
import axios from 'axios';
module.exports = async (req, res) => {

    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&appid=${process.env.OPEN_WEATHER_API}`;

    const weatherResponse = await axios.get(url);

    return res.status(200).json(weatherResponse.data);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you post what the serverless would look like?

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately that's not worked. It's declaring the following error: "errorMessage":"Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'\n    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'\n    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle","stack":["TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON","    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'","

Comment: aaah! it must be `weatherResponse.data`

Comment: Spot on. Thanks for your help!